# flutter firebase, these credentials do not match our records

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hellos devs, I have an Issue, I have a flutter application which when signing up with Google or Apple id, it provides and error (These credentials do not match our records), I searched for it, but didn't find any solution and I deleted most of the records that is related to the gmails I sign up with or my apple id and there are no gmails or apple id inside firebase record users that I sign up with, but it still doesn't work.

[image: Here is the proof]